# RSS feed for unanswered questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tagging, rss

Is there a way to RSS feed the unanswered questions? Because I would find it easier to have an influx of questions about certain tags I like. Is that even possible?

Comment: Do you agree with my edits?